# how to upload files with sequence order in php

Tags: php, file

How to upload files in php and save them by the order 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg etc in directory without using database?i tried this only

```
$dirid=$_GET["dirid"];
if(!is_dir($dirid."/")) {
    mkdir($dirid."/");
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], './'.$dirid.'/'.'1.jpg'))
{
echo "success";
}
```

Comment: you can save the number of the last file  in txt file and give to the new file the next(and then update file), or to glob(scan) the dir to find the last one (bad performence)

Comment: use a counter variable and use it as a filename

Comment: look like http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/flat_file_count_2.htm